# Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with ‘padding=True’ ‘truncation

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, batchsize

To train a Bert LM, I updated the DataCollatorForLanguageModeling function, and it creates another input_ids  as  new_input_ids which is the same size as input_ids. To train bert model it accepts input_ids and new_input_ids in BertForPreTraining class. But facing issues in batch size, getting error
as ' Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length'
I get this issue, comes from this 699 line of this file

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/bd9871657bb9500a9f4437a873db6df5f1ae6dbb/src/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py#L715

Now how can i keep the same size of new_input_ids same as input_ids for every batch